# Facebook og:image is not showing even if the response status is 200

Tags: facebook

Hi I'm having trouble in showing the image when sharing a link thru Facebook.

Here are my meta tags:

```
       <meta property="og:image" content="http://stmaws.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/<?php echo $meta_thumbnail; ?>.jpg" />
       <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
       <meta property="og:image:width" content="300" />
       <meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
       <meta property="og:title" content="Check out what I made on Muserk.com" />
       <meta property="og:site_name" content="Check out what I made on Muserk.com" />
       <meta property="og:description" content="Muserk.com gives you the ability to legally add music to your videos and share them with the world!" />
       <meta property="og:url" content="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" />
```

`$meta_thumbnail` could be something like this: http://stmaws.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/53135cb64f26109a448b4ba6.jpg

My thumbnail image is shared to public so I don't think the problem has something to do with privacy/security.

Image size is 32px of width and 26px of height.

Facebook debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fmuserk.sourcepadstage.com%2Fvideo%2Findex%2F5314f1ba4f261098448b519b

Output from Facebook Debugger:

```
Scrape Information

Response Code   200
Fetched URL http://muserk.sourcepadstage.com/video/index/5314f1ba4f261098448b519b
Canonical URL   http://muserk.sourcepadstage.com/video/index/5314f1ba4f261098448b519b
Object Properties
og:url  http://muserk.sourcepadstage.com/video/index/5314f1ba4f261098448b519b
og:type website
og:title    Check out what I made on Muserk.com
og:image    <IMAGE HAS BEEN DISPLAYED HERE>
og:description  Muserk.com gives you the ability to legally add music to your videos and share them with the world!
og:site_name    Check out what I made on Muserk.com
og:updated_time 1393881547
Raw Open Graph Document Information
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image" content="http://stmaws.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/53135cb64f26109a448b4ba6.jpg" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image:width" content="300" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:title" content="Check out what I made on Muserk.com" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Check out what I made on Muserk.com" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:description" content="Muserk.com gives you the ability to legally add music to your videos and share them with the world!" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:url" content="http://muserk.sourcepadstage.com/video/index/5314f1ba4f261098448b519b" />
URLs
Graph API   https://graph.facebook.com/642413225848487
Scraped URL  See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL
```

EDITS:

Hi I tried to continue sharing the link and it was displayed:

http://d.pr/i/mu2T

But I wonder why it is not showing while sharing the link: http://d.pr/i/9j3l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image is way too small, these are the recommendations:

- Minimum 600x315px
- Recommended: 1200x630px
- Ratio should be 1.91:1

Also, i get an error when i try your Debugger link: "Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped."

Make sure all data is public so Facebook can scrape it.